# Set 'selected' option of populated select menu with ng-options in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I would like to populate a select menu by AngularJS ng-option directive and select a predefined option as default.

The JSON that is fetch by AngularJS looks like:

```
{"AF":"Afghanistan","AX":"\u00c5land Islands","AL":"Albania","DZ":"Algeria","AS":"American Samoa","AD"}
```

The code to populate the select menu works:

```
 angular.module('drpdwnApp', []).controller('drpdwnCtrl', function ($scope, $http) {
     $scope.selectedCountries = null;
     $scope.countries = [];

     $http({
              method: 'GET',
              url: '/api/getCountries'
     }).success(function (result) {
              $scope.countries = result;
     });
 });
```

The HTML of the select menu:

```
<select name="property_country" ng-model="drpdpwnvalue" ng-options="key as value for (key , value) in countries track by key">
     <option value="">Please choose</option>
</select>
```

Now, let's assume that I would like to define the country with key "AL" as selected default option. How can this be achieved?

Answer (score 3):

Just set the `$scope.drpdpwnvalue` to 'AL' in controller:

```
angular.module('drpdwnApp', []).controller('drpdwnCtrl', function ($scope, $http) {
     $scope.selectedCountries = null;
     $scope.countries = [];
     $scope.drpdpwnvalue = 'AL'; // this line is added
     $http({
              method: 'GET',
              url: '/api/getCountries'
     }).success(function (result) {
              $scope.countries = result;
     });
 });
```

`ng-options` works in sync with ng-model, so just manipulate `ng-model` value and the other part is taken care by angular

**UPDATE**
I did some debugging and found out that `track by key` is the problem. So remove it. I also created [working plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/dS7LFO?p=preview), have a look.

Comment: I just noticed that you are using two ng-model declarations `ng-model="drpdpwnvalue" ng-model="selectedCountries"`, you need to remove the last one

Comment: Yes, it is populated correctly. Oh yes, this was a mistake, however removing the second one doesn't make any difference either. I also tried to use your additional code within the success function, but also no luck.

Comment: Alright, now it seems to work, however please check the generated source of the option elements. The value attribute of the options now also includes the datatype ("string:VALUE" for instance). This is why I added "track by key" in my code, which only shows the value without any datatype.

Comment: Don't worry about the string:VALUE, it is only used by angular. Your model will have the right value. I updated the plunker. Try changing selected option, it will alert the value

Comment: Well, I am going to post the data of it to a server side script. I think that I will get a problem as the datatype will probably be submitted as well as it is part of the value attribute.

Comment: If you are going to use angular to submit to server side, you will not have the datatype prepended to the value. But if you use bare javascript to get the value, you will definitely have the datatype as part of the value

Comment: I am not using angular for it but good old form submit. So is there no possibility to have this stupid datatype declaration removed from the value attribute?

Answer (score 0):

try [ng-selected](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngSelected) on option element.

```
<select ng-model="drpdpwnvalue" ng-model="selectedCountries">
     <option value="{{key}}" ng-repeat="key as value for (key , value) in countries track by key" ng-selected="key === 'AL'">{{value}}</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Thank you, but is there no solution with ng-options? Furthermore I would rather like to prevent using curly braces as these are used by my template engine as well.

Answer (score 0):

I finally achieved it by simply using JQuery as both Angular solutions didn't work for me properly:

```
    $( document ).ready(function() {
        $.getJSON("/api/getCountries", function(result) {
            var options = $("select[name=property_country]");

            $.each(result, function(key, value) {
                options.append($("<option />").val(key).text(value));
            });

            $('select[name=property_country] option[value="AL"]').attr("selected", "selected");
        });
    });
```

However this is just for reference and will not be the accepted answer as it is achieved by JQuery.